# Why does my loss function fluctuate so much?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, feedforward-neural-networks, loss, multilayer-perceptrons

I have a loss function that I'm trying to maximise using a neural network.

While it does appear to increase and plateau over the training, it does so in a very "noisy" manner, spiking up and down, as opposed to smoothly. Below is an example (y-axis is loss, x-axis is number of epochs).

[image]

I'm having a hard time diagnosing why this might be. Is it my learning rate that's too high (1e-4 with Adam optimiser)? Is it due to my neural network architecture (a MLP of structure input_dim --> 512 --> 256 --> 128 --> 1) being too complex/not complex enough? Or could it be another factor?

EDIT:

In response to the comment by Edoardo, I am trying to implement MINE (Mutual Information Neural Estimation). MINE computes a lower bound on the mutual information between two variables. The lower bound it computes is the supremum, over a class of functions, of a particular expression (more details can be found here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.04062.pdf). The family of functions is chosen to be a neural network of a particular architecture parametrised by parameters $\theta \in \Theta$ (each element in $\Theta$ corresponds to a unique neural network, i.e. function, in the family), and taking the supremum over  of the expression in question all possible neural networks is essentially equivalent to optimising the parameters to maximise the expression.

Comment: Why are you maximising rather than minimising the loss function? Just asking cause it's a very odd thing to do (maybe your doing reinforcement learning and dealing with a reward function rather than a loss function?). So if you have a specific reason for that it will definitely help to know it in order to answer the question.

Comment: @EdoardoGuerriero Thanks for your reply. I've added a paragraph to elaborate on why I'm maximising a "loss function". In retrospect, I guess my use of loss function was misleading - perhaps I should have said "objective function" instead.